# Mp4 cannot play on iOS by request spring mvc server resource, but working on Nginx access mp4 file directly

Tags: ios, spring-mvc, nginx, mp4

I have two scenario when play mp4 file on iOS devices.

**MP4 access by Nginx is working:** 
Put mp4 file in /html and using following configure, then iOS devices and chrome browser can play mp4 files properly.

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:80 default_server;
  location ~ ^/storage\/*.mp4 {  
    root html;
  }
}
```

**MP4 access by Tomcat Spring MVC is not working:** When I request by Spring mvc restful API and return ResponseEntity contains Resource Object, in chrome browser will receive and play mp4 properly. But iOS devices not working

```
@GetMapping(value = "/storage/{filename:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<org.springframework.core.io.Resource> accessStorageFile(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String filename) throws IOException {
    org.springframework.core.io.Resource resource = storageUtil.loadAsResource(filename);
    InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
    String contentType = FileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap().getContentType(resource.getFile());
    contentType = resource.getFilename().contains(".mp4") ? "video/mp4" : contentType;
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(contentType));
    responseHeaders.setContentLength(resource.getFile().length());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(inputStreamResource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> import java.io.BufferedInputStream; import java.io.File; import
>   java.io.IOException; import java.io.InputStream; import
>   java.io.OutputStream; import java.nio.file.Files; import
>   java.nio.file.Path; import java.nio.file.Paths; import
>   java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime; import java.time.LocalDateTime;
>   import java.time.ZoneId; import java.time.ZoneOffset; import
>   java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.List;
>   import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream; import
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; import
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; import
>   org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
>
> /**  *  * @author David 1  */ public class MultipartFileSender {
>
> ```
> private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 20480; // ..bytes = 20KB.
> private static final long DEFAULT_EXPIRE_TIME = 604800000L; // ..ms = 1 week.
> private static final String MULTIPART_BOUNDARY = "MULTIPART_BYTERANGES";
>
> Path filepath;
> HttpServletRequest request;
> HttpServletResponse response;
>
> public MultipartFileSender() {
> }
>
> public static MultipartFileSender fromPath(Path path) {
>     return new MultipartFileSender().setFilepath(path);
> }
>
> public static MultipartFileSender fromFile(File file) {
>     return new MultipartFileSender().setFilepath(file.toPath());
> }
>
> public static MultipartFileSender fromURIString(String uri) {
>     return new MultipartFileSender().setFilepath(Paths.get(uri));
> }
>
> //** internal setter **//
> private MultipartFileSender setFilepath(Path filepath) {
>     this.filepath = filepath;
>     return this;
> }
>
> public MultipartFileSender with(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
>     request = httpRequest;
>     return this;
> }
>
> public MultipartFileSender with(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
>     response = httpResponse;
>     return this;
> }
>
> public void serveResource() throws Exception {
>     if (response == null || request == null) {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     if (!Files.exists(filepath)) {
>         System.out.println("File doesn't exist at URI : {" + filepath.toAbsolutePath().toString() + "}");
>         response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
>         return;
>     }
>
>     Long length = Files.size(filepath);
>     String fileName = filepath.getFileName().toString();
>     FileTime lastModifiedObj = Files.getLastModifiedTime(filepath);
>
>     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fileName) || lastModifiedObj == null) {
>         response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
>         return;
>     }
>     long lastModified = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(lastModifiedObj.toInstant(),
> ```
>
> ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.systemDefault().getId())).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
>           String contentType = "video/mp4";
>
> ```
>     // Validate request headers for caching ---------------------------------------------------
>     // If-None-Match header should contain "*" or ETag. If so, then return 304.
>     String ifNoneMatch = request.getHeader("If-None-Match");
>     if (ifNoneMatch != null && HttpUtils.matches(ifNoneMatch, fileName)) {
>         response.setHeader("ETag", fileName); // Required in 304.
>         response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // If-Modified-Since header should be greater than LastModified. If so, then return 304.
>     // This header is ignored if any If-None-Match header is specified.
>     long ifModifiedSince = request.getDateHeader("If-Modified-Since");
>     if (ifNoneMatch == null && ifModifiedSince != -1 && ifModifiedSince + 1000 > lastModified) {
>         response.setHeader("ETag", fileName); // Required in 304.
>         response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Validate request headers for resume ----------------------------------------------------
>     // If-Match header should contain "*" or ETag. If not, then return 412.
>     String ifMatch = request.getHeader("If-Match");
>     if (ifMatch != null && !HttpUtils.matches(ifMatch, fileName)) {
>         response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // If-Unmodified-Since header should be greater than LastModified. If not, then return 412.
>     long ifUnmodifiedSince = request.getDateHeader("If-Unmodified-Since");
>     if (ifUnmodifiedSince != -1 && ifUnmodifiedSince + 1000 <= lastModified) {
>         response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Validate and process range -------------------------------------------------------------
>     // Prepare some variables. The full Range represents the complete file.
>     Range full = new Range(0, length - 1, length);
>     List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<>();
>
>     // Validate and process Range and If-Range headers.
>     String range = request.getHeader("Range");
>     if (range != null) {
>
>         // Range header should match format "bytes=n-n,n-n,n-n...". If not, then return 416.
>         if (!range.matches("^bytes=\\d*-\\d*(,\\d*-\\d*)*$")) {
>             response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes */" + length); // Required in 416.
>             response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
>             return;
>         }
>
>         String ifRange = request.getHeader("If-Range");
>         if (ifRange != null && !ifRange.equals(fileName)) {
>             try {
>                 long ifRangeTime = request.getDateHeader("If-Range"); // Throws IAE if invalid.
>                 if (ifRangeTime != -1) {
>                     ranges.add(full);
>                 }
>             } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) {
>                 ranges.add(full);
>             }
>         }
>
>         // If any valid If-Range header, then process each part of byte range.
>         if (ranges.isEmpty()) {
>             for (String part : range.substring(6).split(",")) {
>                 // Assuming a file with length of 100, the following examples returns bytes at:
>                 // 50-80 (50 to 80), 40- (40 to length=100), -20 (length-20=80 to length=100).
>                 long start = Range.sublong(part, 0, part.indexOf("-"));
>                 long end = Range.sublong(part, part.indexOf("-") + 1, part.length());
>
>                 if (start == -1) {
>                     start = length - end;
>                     end = length - 1;
>                 } else if (end == -1 || end > length - 1) {
>                     end = length - 1;
>                 }
>
>                 // Check if Range is syntactically valid. If not, then return 416.
>                 if (start > end) {
>                     response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes */" + length); // Required in 416.
>                     response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
>                     return;
>                 }
>
>                 // Add range.                    
>                 ranges.add(new Range(start, end, length));
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     // Prepare and initialize response --------------------------------------------------------
>     // Get content type by file name and set content disposition.
>     String disposition = "inline";
>
>     // If content type is unknown, then set the default value.
>     // For all content types, see: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp
>     // To add new content types, add new mime-mapping entry in web.xml.
>     if (contentType == null) {
>         contentType = "application/octet-stream";
>     } else if (!contentType.startsWith("image")) {
>         // Else, expect for images, determine content disposition. If content type is supported by
>         // the browser, then set to inline, else attachment which will pop a 'save as' dialogue.
>         String accept = request.getHeader("Accept");
>         disposition = accept != null && HttpUtils.accepts(accept, contentType) ? "inline" : "attachment";
>     }
>     System.out.println("Content-Type : {" + contentType + "}");
>     // Initialize response.
>     response.reset();
>     response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
>     response.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
>     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition + ";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
>     System.out.println("Content-Disposition : {" + disposition + "}");
>     response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
>     response.setHeader("ETag", fileName);
>     response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", lastModified);
>     response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + DEFAULT_EXPIRE_TIME);
>
>     // Send requested file (part(s)) to client ------------------------------------------------
>     // Prepare streams.
>     try (InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(filepath));
>             OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream()) {
>
>         if (ranges.isEmpty() || ranges.get(0) == full) {
>
>             // Return full file.
>             System.out.println("Return full file");
>             response.setContentType(contentType);
>             response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + full.start + "-" + full.end + "/" + full.total);
>             response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(full.length));
>             Range.copy(input, output, length, full.start, full.length);
>
>         } else if (ranges.size() == 1) {
>
>             // Return single part of file.
>             Range r = ranges.get(0);
>             System.out.println("Return 1 part of file : from ({" + r.start + "}) to ({" + r.end + "})");
>             response.setContentType(contentType);
>             response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + r.start + "-" + r.end + "/" + r.total);
>             response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(r.length));
>             response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT); // 206.
>
>             // Copy single part range.
>             Range.copy(input, output, length, r.start, r.length);
>
>         } else {
>
>             // Return multiple parts of file.
>             response.setContentType("multipart/byteranges; boundary=" + MULTIPART_BOUNDARY);
>             response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT); // 206.
>
>             // Cast back to ServletOutputStream to get the easy println methods.
>             ServletOutputStream sos = (ServletOutputStream) output;
>
>             // Copy multi part range.
>             for (Range r : ranges) {
>                 System.out.println("Return multi part of file : from ({" + r.start + "}) to ({" + r.end + "})");
>                 // Add multipart boundary and header fields for every range.
>                 sos.println();
>                 sos.println("--" + MULTIPART_BOUNDARY);
>                 sos.println("Content-Type: " + contentType);
>                 sos.println("Content-Range: bytes " + r.start + "-" + r.end + "/" + r.total);
>
>                 // Copy single part range of multi part range.
>                 Range.copy(input, output, length, r.start, r.length);
>             }
>
>             // End with multipart boundary.
>             sos.println();
>             sos.println("--" + MULTIPART_BOUNDARY + "--");
>         }
>     }
>
> }
>
> private static class Range {
>
>     long start;
>     long end;
>     long length;
>     long total;
>
>     /**
>      * Construct a byte range.
>      *
>      * @param start Start of the byte range.
>      * @param end End of the byte range.
>      * @param total Total length of the byte source.
>      */
>     public Range(long start, long end, long total) {
>         this.start = start;
>         this.end = end;
>         this.length = end - start + 1;
>         this.total = total;
>     }
>
>     public static long sublong(String value, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
>         String substring = value.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
>         return (substring.length() > 0) ? Long.parseLong(substring) : -1;
>     }
>
>     private static void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output, long inputSize, long start, long length) throws IOException {
>         byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
>         int read;
>
>         if (inputSize == length) {
>             // Write full range.
>             while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
>                 output.write(buffer, 0, read);
>                 output.flush();
>             }
>         } else {
>             input.skip(start);
>             long toRead = length;
>
>             while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
>                 if ((toRead -= read) > 0) {
>                     output.write(buffer, 0, read);
>                     output.flush();
>                 } else {
>                     output.write(buffer, 0, (int) toRead + read);
>                     output.flush();
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> private static class HttpUtils {
>
>     /**
>      * Returns true if the given accept header accepts the given value.
>      *
>      * @param acceptHeader The accept header.
>      * @param toAccept The value to be accepted.
>      * @return True if the given accept header accepts the given value.
>      */
>     public static boolean accepts(String acceptHeader, String toAccept) {
>         String[] acceptValues = acceptHeader.split("\\s*(,|;)\\s*");
>         Arrays.sort(acceptValues);
>
>         return Arrays.binarySearch(acceptValues, toAccept) > -1
>                 || Arrays.binarySearch(acceptValues, toAccept.replaceAll("/.*$", "/*")) > -1
>                 || Arrays.binarySearch(acceptValues, "*/*") > -1;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Returns true if the given match header matches the given value.
>      *
>      * @param matchHeader The match header.
>      * @param toMatch The value to be matched.
>      * @return True if the given match header matches the given value.
>      */
>     public static boolean matches(String matchHeader, String toMatch) {
>         String[] matchValues = matchHeader.split("\\s*,\\s*");
>         Arrays.sort(matchValues);
>         return Arrays.binarySearch(matchValues, toMatch) > -1
>                 || Arrays.binarySearch(matchValues, "*") > -1;
>     }
> } }
> ```

use is in your controller and make sure you are not use @RestController
you should use @Controller, and following class in void method 
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getFile")
    public void getFile(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws Exception {
        MultipartFileSender.fromPath(Paths.get("D:\8561523973120206.mp4"))
                .with(httpRequest)
                .with(httpResponse)
                .serveResource();
    }